# Mount iso9660 sd card

Tags: arch-linux, mount

I'd like to mount my sd-card, but that doesn't work. Do I have to give an extra parameter to mount?

```
$ mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdarch
mount: Falscher Dateisystemtyp, ungültige Optionen, der
Superblock von /dev/mmcblk0p1 ist beschädigt, fehlende
Kodierungsseite oder ein anderer Fehler

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.

$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE  LABEL          UUID                                         MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1      ext4    arch        2f47d944-a40c-4edb-bf81-aa4b978b1a6b /
└─sda2      swap    swap        cb6c3da9-b65a-451b-96a3-2f3697d7afd0 [SWAP]
sr0                                                                  
mmcblk0     iso9660 ARCH_201305 2013-05-01-07-12-33-00               
└─mmcblk0p1 iso9660 ARCH_201305 2013-05-01-07-12-33-00               

$ dmesg
...
[  231.389964] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  231.392957] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[  231.393164] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 1165.652241] perf samples too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50100
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filesystem is iso9660 try to mount using the following command:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdarch
```

Comment: Why the `-o loop`?

Comment: That didn't work! `[linus@linus_linux-notebook ~]$ sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sdarch
Passwort: 
mount: /dev/loop0 ist schreibgeschützt, wird eingehängt im Nur-Lese-Modus
mount: Falscher Dateisystemtyp, ungültige Optionen, der
Superblock von /dev/loop0 ist beschädigt, fehlende
Kodierungsseite oder ein anderer Fehler

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
`

Comment: I try, to mount the SD-Card with udiskie. That works! But when I try to mount my CD (sr0), it doesn't still better.